# support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 - не удается подключить

Tags: android, android-studio

Не получается перевести свой проект на v7:28.0.0. Взял и создал вообще пустой дефолтный проект, что студия предлагает на выбор при создании проекта. В частности взял Google Maps. Сразу при создании проекта указал Minimum API Level 28, что бы посмотреть как студия автоматом все создаст. Только после создания проекта, сразу ошибка, строка

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Стала подчеркиваться красным. Хорошо, гууглим. Прочел, что надо подключить

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Прописал. После пересобрал этот проект. Красным подчеркиваться перестало. Только в дефолтном MapsActivity не может подключиться

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

тупо красное. И соотвественно, в моем проекте, так же. Только еще куча всего не может подключиться: annotations и т.д.

Да, находил, что надо подключить:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0'
```

Только это не помогает. Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете AndroidX вам нужно подгружать и использовать библиотеки AndroidX.

По [ссылке](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) можно посмотреть какие библиотеки нужно использовать на AndroidX вместо старых.

Comment: да, уже и это нашел, что в таком случае надо подключать: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

Comment: только это ни каким образом не помогает. 
```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```
вот это все красное...

Comment: Потому что если вы используете androidx, вы не можете использовать вообще ничего из support библиотек. Откройте меню Refactoring и выберите Migrate to AndroidX, чтобы автоматически заменить все упоминания support на androidx